# pyspark read jdbc to get lower and upper bound values of a DB2 table

Tags: python-2.7, pyspark

I am using the below code to get the lower and upper bound values to import a table from DB2.

Code:

```
bound_query = "(select min(col1), max(col1) from ccdb2.table1) t"

bound_query_result = spark.read.format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", url) \
    .option("driver", driver) \
    .option("dbtable", bound_query) \
    .option("user", user) \
    .option("password", pswd).load()
```

Error:

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.eo: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, SQLERRMC=1, DRIVER=3.53.95
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.bd.a(bd.java:676)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.bd.a(bd.java:60)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.bd.a(bd.java:127)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.gm.c(gm.java:2484)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.gm.d(gm.java:2461)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.gm.a(gm.java:1962)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.db.g(db.java:138)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.db.a(db.java:38)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.t.a(t.java:32)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.sb.h(sb.java:141)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.gm.bb(gm.java:1933)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.hm.ec(hm.java:2558)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.hm.e(hm.java:3259)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.hm.Rb(hm.java:583)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.hm.executeQuery(hm.java:557)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD.compute(JDBCRDD.scala:301)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

When i am just giving select * from table, there is no issue. When the MIN and MAX functions are used its giving this error.

Is there any other way to get the boundary values for spark db2 import?

Hadoop Version : 3.2
Spark : 2.3.2
Python : 2.7.5

Thanks,
Amrutha K

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't want to go with this solution? as this one is industry standard solution or put more info about your use case.

Comment: this is throwing error when executed.

Comment: This error is related to DB2 and not spark, this error can occur for the following situations: v The specified column is not a column of any of the source or target tables or views of the statement. In a SELECT or DELETE statement, the specified column is not a column of any of the tables or views that are identified in a FROM clause in the statement.

Comment: But when i executed the same query in DB2 table result is showing up.

Comment: Check if this query works for you, bound_query = "SELECT min_val, max_val FROM (select min(col1) as min_val, max(col1) as max_val from ccdb2.table1) t".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this works, here made changes to query and instead of dbtable used query option.

```
bound_query = "SELECT min_val, max_val FROM (select min(col1) as min_val, max(col1) as max_val from ccdb2.table1) t"

bound_query_result = spark.read.format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", url) \
    .option("driver", driver) \
    .option("query", bound_query) \
    .option("user", user) \
    .option("password", pswd).load()
```

Comment: Thank you. I have made a small change and it worked. bound_query = "(SELECT * FROM ( select MIN(col1) as min_val, MAX(col1) as max_val from ccdb2.table1) t ) x"